# How can I get a list of users who like my Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using Graph API and the closest thing I found is page_fan table. but it's page_id column is not indexable...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get a listing of the page fans (the latest 500) via:

https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=PAGE_ID

However, this is not via the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

Many of us have tried and failed to find a way to get a list of users who've liked you page.  Facebook seems pretty tight about not letting that information out.  Your best bet is to post on your wall and hope your page's wall post is seen on the liked personal feed by facebook algorithm.

Comment: Didn't quite get how it helps me... I need a list of people who Like my page (not necessarily for posting on their walls).